# How to list distinct keys of an index?

Tags: oracle, indexing

user_indexes table has a column named 'distinct keys'. Does this value represent the number of distinct keys in the column indexed. In that case, is there a way to list all those keys ?

Comment: Please note, `distinct keys` is just a statistic - its accuracy is dependent on how long it's been since stats were gathered, how much DML activity has occurred on the table since then, and what sample size was used to generate the stats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Does this value represent the number of distinct keys in the column indexed.`

Yes, it does represent the number of distinct indexed values.

`In that case, is there a way to list all those keys ?`

You'll have to manually execute `SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name` to get list of distinct values. There is no system view, which stores the distinct values associated to an indexed column.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're interested in the distinct values in an *index*, you would be better off running a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL;
```

This is very likely to use the index to return the distinct values very quickly, without having to do a full table scan and a sort.

(Note: if the column already has a validated NOT NULL constraint, you won't need the "IS NOT NULL" where clause).